# Why does this SetState not work? Setting the state in the child of a child component

Tags: react-hooks, create-react-app, setstate

I'm trying to use setState to change my my layout. But for my react app to work I need the state in my app.js. So diffrent childeren can access it and edit if needed. but i'm getting Setstate in not a function. Whjy is that and how do i fix it?

The app.js

```
function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Main />
      <Card setIsOpen={setIsOpen} isOpen={isOpen} />
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The cards.js component child of app.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Card = (setIsOpen, isOpen) => {
  return (
    <section className="cards">
      <CloseBtn setIsOpen={setIsOpen} isOpen={isOpen} />
      <div className="cards-content webdesign-content">
        <WebIntro />
        <SkillSection />
        <Seo />
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

The closebtn component child of card.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const CloseBtn = (setIsOpen, isOpen) => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          console.log(!isOpen);
          setIsOpen(!isOpen);                 //==>Not WORKING
        }}
        className={buttonClassArr}
      >
        <i>Close</i>
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default CloseBtn;
```

I've tried console.log all over but do not get a usefull result.

Comment: Props in react require desturcturing on all of your components, for example `const CloseBtn = ({ setIsOpen, isOpen }) => `.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you passed the props. You need to receive the props object and destructure the required props from it.

```
// destruct the props inside curly braces
const Card = ({ setIsOpen, isOpen }) => {
return (
    <section className="cards">
      <CloseBtn setIsOpen={setIsOpen} isOpen={isOpen} />
    </section>
  );
};

// destruct the props inside curly braces
const CloseBtn = ({ setIsOpen, isOpen }) => {
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        console.log(!isOpen);
        setIsOpen(!isOpen); // This should work now
      }}
      className={buttonClassArr}
    >
      <i>Close</i>
    </button>
  );
};
```